# jQuery ui autocomplete ipv4

Tags: php, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery UI Autocomplete as helper in a form. When I try to use it to search from a list of available IPs it never filter the results, no matter the number of characters (numbers) I type it always returns the complete list.
How can I correct it?
I am using this code http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache
The JSON generated from a PHP file is similiar to this (I have reduced the number of results):

["192.168.3.2","192.168.3.3","192.168.3.4","192.168.3.5","192.168.3.6","192.168.3.7","192.168.3.8","192.168.3.9","192.168.3.10"]

[Edit]

The form page code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote with caching</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <style>
            .ui-autocomplete-loading {
                background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var cache = {};
                $("#birds").autocomplete({
                    minLength: 2,
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        var term = request.term;
                        if (term in cache) {
                            response(cache[ term ]);
                            return;
                        }
                        $.getJSON("tab-ip-autocomplete.php", request, function(data, status, xhr) {
                            cache[ term ] = data;
                            response(data);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
            <input id="birds" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP to JSON code:

```
<?php
include_once 'conn.php';

INET_NTOA(ipv4) LIKE :ipv4";

$autocomplete = "SELECT * FROM vteste;";

$STH = $DBH->prepare($autocomplete);
$STH->bindParam(':ipv4', $ipv4, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->execute();
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $STH->fetch();


/* gera json */

$arr = array();

while ($row = $STH->fetch()):
    $arr[] = $row['ipv4'];
endwhile;

$json = json_encode($arr);
echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the javascript code you are using to set up the autocompleter?

Comment: I'm using the exact code from the jQuery UI's site. Copied and pasted.

Comment: You must be doing something at least a little different, no? The example code on the site is about birds, not ip addresses, and it references a `search.php` that you didn't mention. Posting the code in your question is good form anyway, so it's all here at once to see.

Comment: The javascript and html code is the same from the site what changes is the data, in this case IP addresses. At least I guess that the PHP to generate the JSON is correct.

Answer (score 1):

When using a remote datasource, the jQueryUI AutoComplete doesn't filter your results - it is down to the script which provides the data to send over only matching results.

From the http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source:

> The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query
>   string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should
>   use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is
>   set to "http://example.com" and the user types foo, a GET request
>   would be made to http://example.com?term=foo. The data itself can be
>   in the same format as the local data described above.